# derivative of an integral from 0 to x when x is negative?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Given a function $$F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{t + 8}{t^3 - 9}dt,$$ is $F'(x)$ different when $x<0$, when $x=0$ and when $x>0$?

When $x<0$, is $$F'(x) = - \frac{x + 8}{x^3 - 9}$$ ... since you can't evaluate an integral going from a smaller number to a bigger number? That's what I initially thought, but when I graphed the antiderivative the intervals of increase and decrease were different from the ones in my calculation.

EDIT: Yes, I was talking about that identity. 
So is $$F'(x) = \frac{x + 8}{x^3 - 9}$$ or $$F'(x) = -\frac{x + 8}{x^3 - 9}$$ ??

EDIT: thanks for the answers! but what happens when x is bigger than 9^1/3? The derivative is also the same? Btw, when x = 0 shouldn't F(x) = 0 and hence F'(x) = 0?

Answer (score 1):

No, we have
$$F'(x)=\frac{x+8}{x^3-9}$$
for all $x<\sqrt[3]{9}$. The limitation is due to the fact that the integral is meaningful only when the interval doesn't contain $\sqrt[3]{9}$ and so we must consider only the interval $(-\infty,\sqrt[3]{9})$ that contains $0$.

If $b<a$, one sets, *by definition*,
$$
\int_a^b f(t)\,dt=-\int_b^a f(t)\,dt
$$
so the equality
$$
\int_a^c f(t)\,dt=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt+\int_b^c f(t)\,dt
$$
without restrictions on the limits of integration, provided we don't jump over points where $f$ is not defined so that all the integrals make sense.

This relation is what the fundamental theorem of calculus relies on. Remember that, for continuous $f$, there exists $\xi$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t)\,dt=f(\xi)
$$
where $\xi\in[a,b]$ if $a<b$. Therefore, for $h>0$,
$$
\int_0^{x+h}f(t)\,dt-\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=
\int_x^0 f(t)\,dt+\int_0^{x+h}f(t)\,dt-\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=
\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)\,dt=hf(\xi)
$$
for some $\xi\in[x,x+h]$, so that
$$
\lim_{h\to0+}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=f(x).
$$
Similarly for the limit from the left.

Answer (score 0):

We have got the identity $\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = -\int\limits_{b}^{a}f(x)dx$. Which can easy be verified by writing it out. Im guessing this is what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you presume we can't evaluate an integral going from a smaller number to a bigger number? The restriction on being positive is for areas, not integrals. The upper and lower limits can be any numbers, within the specified set of numbers(real or complex).

And no, $F'(x)$ has the same expression for all conditions, of course it may take different values.

Answer (score 0):

Given any interval $I\subset{\mathbb R}$ and a continuous function $f:\>I\to{\mathbb R}$ the *indefinite integral* of $f$ over $I$ is the set of all functions $F:\>I\to{\mathbb R}$ (called *primitives* of $f$) that satisfy
$$F'(x)=f(x)\qquad\forall x\in I\ .$$
This set depends only on ($I$ and) $f$; therefore it is allowed to denote it by
$$\int f(x)\>dx\ .$$
Given any two points $a$, $b\in I$, the difference $F(b)-F(a)$, computed for an arbitrary primitive $F$ of the given $f$, is called the *definite integral of $f$ from $a$ to $b$*. This difference does not depend on the chosen primitive $F$, nor on the name of the variable used, but only on $f$, $a$, and $b$. Therefore it is allowed to denote it by
$$\int_a^b f(t)\ dt\ ,$$
or using some other "dummy variable" instead of $t$.
From the definition it is clear that $${d\over dx}\int_a^x f(t)\>dt={d\over dx}\bigl(F(x)-F(a)\bigr)=F'(x)=f(x)\ .$$
What does all of this have to do with the FTC? Well, the FTC says that when $a<b$ then
$$\int\nolimits_{[a,b]} f(x)\>{\rm d}x=\int_a^b f(x)\>dx\ .$$
Here the LHS is a limit of Riemann sums (an "area"), and the RHS is a difference of end-values.